# you need to call create() at least once to create the singleton in React native

Tags: react-native, background-process

I'm working on Background Task but the when I'll be run the app It will give a error like `you need to call create() at least once to create the singleton` I'm using `react-native-background-task` library for running background task

Answer (score 2):

add this like in the onCreate() method in the MainApplication.java

```
BackgroundTaskPackage.useContext(this);
```

Comment: This gives out this error:
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

Answer (score 2):

For future readers

## Automatic method

Run this on console

```
react-native link react-native-background-task
```

## Manual Method

Edit `MainApplication.java`

add this line at top:

```
import com.jamesisaac.rnbackgroundtask.BackgroundTaskPackage;
```

then in onCreate() method

```
BackgroundTaskPackage.useContext(this);
```